# Find the prime decomposition of $(2) $ in $\mathbb Z\left[ \frac{ 1 + \sqrt n }{2 } \right]$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer such that $ n \equiv 1 $ mod $4$.

Let $\mathbb Z \left[ \frac{ 1 + \sqrt n }{ 2} \right]$ be our ring. Let $(2)$ be the ideal generated by $2$.

What is the prime decomposition of $(2)$ in $\mathbb Z \left[ \frac{ 1 + \sqrt n }{ 2} \right]$?

Comment: It depends. $(2)$ is inert, when $n=5$, but splits, when $n=17$. All according to whether $2$ is a QR modulo $n$ or not. This in turn depends on the residue class of $n$ modulo $8$.

Comment: If the ring is a unique factorization domain, then it's a very simple matter. If $n \equiv 5 \mod 8$, then 2 is prime, but if $n \equiv 1 \mod 8$, then 2 is composite (this is Theorem 9.24 in Niven-Zuckerman). I might post a more complete answer about this later on.

But if the ring is *not* a unique factorization domain, things get more complicated. For one thing, we must say "irreducible" rather than "prime," lest we wish to incur the wrath of pedants. And it could happen that there is an indicator suggesting that 2 is reducible but it turns out to irreducible.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/wiki/2#Factorization_of_2_in_some_quadratic_integer_rings

Comment: @AlonsodelArte OP talks about the *ideal* to be factored. I strongly assume they want a prime decomposition *into ideals*.

Comment: Not to gang up on Alfonzo here, but the OP did use the word "ideal" in his question.

Comment: You're right, Bob. For what it's worth, I find the question of the factorization of 2 the integer in different rings quite interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let ${\cal O}_K$ the ring of integers of $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{m})$ ($m$ any squarefree integer). Then the ideal $2{\cal O}_K$ factorizes as follows:

- $2{\cal O}_K=(2,\sqrt{m})^2$ if $2|m$
- $2{\cal O}_K=(2,1+\sqrt{m})^2$ if $m\equiv3\bmod4$,
- $2{\cal O}_K=(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{m}}2)(2,\frac{1-\sqrt{m}}2)$ if $m\equiv1\bmod8$,
- $2{\cal O}_K$ is prime if $m\equiv5\bmod8$.

Once these decompositions are given, proving them is a simple exercise.

Mind that sometimes the ideals in the decomposition may be actually principal (generated by one element). This obviously happen when ${\cal O}_K$ is a PID.